# Is there a way to filter kafka record before deserialization when using reactor kafka

Tags: filter, spring-kafka, reactive, reactor-kafka

I'm consuming messages from kafka using **reactor-kafka** and **spring-kafka**, all in a spring-boot application.
I'm trying to filter records, based on some headers , before deserialization.
currently I have a solution by using a customAvroDeserializer.

is there any chance I can use RecordFilterStrategy to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; `RecordFilterStrategy` is only available in `spring-kafka` (Spring for Apache Kafka).

In any case, that is only applied after deserialization.

You could use a custom deserializer that returns `null` (or some other special value) in the `record.value()` but you would still need to filter those in your reactor pipeline.